# nginx rewrite downloads instead of opening php files

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I added this lines into the virtual.conf in nginx. the redirection is working fine, but it downloads the file instead of opening it.

```
rewrite ^/img-(.*).html /img.php?id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/slide-(.*).html /slider.php?id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/page-(.*).html /page.php?name=$1 last;
rewrite ^/contact.html$ /contact.php last;
```

I was trying to translate this .htaccess to nginx:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^img-(.*).html img.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^slide-(.*).html slider.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-(.*).html page.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact.html$ contact.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx was old. I needed to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess… no PHP installed?
I would try to show a simple page With PHP info command. In this context it is probably better to talk about execution not to open .

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3vgV65Ddlfb09uWjJmMTYtRU0/edit?usp=sharing Yes, PHP is installed and working fine. Check the link for a php info screenshot.